# Converting from rxvt login batch to mintty in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, rxvt, mintty

Here is my cygwin.bat file for starting a cygwin terminal window via rxvt.

```
@echo off

C:

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin\bin

REM SHELL needed for any screen instances started from bash
set SHELL=/bin/bash
set HOME=C:\cygwin\home\Dragos
set HOMEDRIVE=C:
set HOMEPATH=\cygwin\home\Dragos

REM This part is for chere generated context menu item "Open Bash shell here"
REM 
if not [%1]==[] (
  C:\cygwin\bin\cygpath %1 > tmpFile
  set /p startingpath= < tmpFile
  del tmpFile
)

if "%startingpath%"=="" C:\cygwin\bin\rxvt --loginShell -sr
if not "%startingpath%"=="" start C:\cygwin\bin\rxvt --loginShell -e /bin/bash --login -c "cd '%startingpath%'; exec /bin/bash -rcfile ~/.bashrc"
exit
```

I would like to switch from rxvt to mintty but I do not want to lose the ability to open a cygwin terminal cd'd to that path when right-clicking on a folder and selecting "Open Bash shell here". The default mintty command out of the box is

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

I did

```
man mintty
```

but all I see that is the equivalent of rxvt --loginShell -e option in mintty is --exec.

Is there a way to pass my preferred login shell (bash) and some additional params to mintty the same way I passed them to rxvt above?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. I'd be very interested to see what others have as their cygwin.bat

```
@echo off

C:

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin\bin

REM SHELL needed for any screen instances started from bash
set SHELL=/bin/bash
set HOME=C:\cygwin\home\Dragos
set HOMEDRIVE=C:
set HOMEPATH=\cygwin\home\Dragos

REM 

if not [%1]==[] (
  C:\cygwin\bin\cygpath %1 > tmpFile
  set /p startingpath= < tmpFile
  del tmpFile
)

if "%startingpath%"=="" start C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --icon /Cygwin-Terminal.ico --size 140,50 --exec /bin/bash --login -c "exec /bin/bash -rcfile ~/.bashrc"
if not "%startingpath%"=="" start C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --icon /Cygwin-Terminal.ico --size 140,50 --exec /bin/bash --login -c "cd '%startingpath%'; exec /bin/bash -rcfile ~/.bashrc"
exit
```

Comment: A nice advantage to switching from rxvt to mintty is that you can do columnar select by pressing Alt key while selecting text from the term window.